# Custom JSON to POJO mapper

Tags: java, json, resttemplate, pojo

### Context

I am trying to receive data using RestTemplate GET request, the server returns the data that I need in JSON format, the response contains all data that I need, but it also contains a lot of excess data and I don't want to add excessive fields that will contain excessive data to my POJO to map it automatically.

## The question is

Can I somehow make a custom mapper, to map only certain JSON fields to my java class? Would appreciate any help

### Some code samples

Previously i mapped JSON straight to my POJO like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Foo> response = new RestTemplate(requestFactory)
            .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Foo>(){});
```

but now the service I am using changed its API and sends data in a totally different format. It would be really unpleasant to change my java classes, so I wonder if I can get to map only needed data

And the json i get looks like this:

```
[{
    "idReadable": "idR",
    "customFields": [{
        "projectCustomField": {
            "field": {
                "name": "Name",
                "$type": "type"
            },
            "$type": "type"
        },
        "value": {
            "name": "Value",
            "$type": "type"
        },
        "$type": "type"
    }],
    "id": "id",
    "$type": "type"
}]
```

and I need only two "name" values

### The solution

As @mostneededrabbit suggested in comments the solution was to write custom Deserializer extending StdDeserializer for the RestTemplate inside of which looks something like this:

```
    ArrayNode nodeList = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    HashMap<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
    List<Issue> foos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (JsonNode node : nodeList) {
        String id = node.get("id").asText();
        issues.add(new Foo(id));
    }
```

And to actually set it to work you would need to do something like this before sending the request:

```
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Foo.class, new FooDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    var converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    var restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore unneeded fields by putting this on top of your class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Then keep only the fields that are needed in the class.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do this via the annotation due to complex response nesting system, but either way I'm curious if there a way to implement some type of mapper?

Comment: Added the json i'm trying to convert, maybe it'll help to understand the task better

Comment: @mmmetafool Is traversing the JSON is the type of solution you are looking for? Or something more "out of the box"?

Comment: I guess traversing is fine if i won't have to process response more than once, would be great if i could process it at the same moment i get the data at RestTemplate. Can i maybe configure my own deserializer?

Comment: @mmmetafool Maybe this will help - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization